# Javascript: reassign array value using querySelectorAll() failed to update

Tags: javascript, dom

`path = element[i].nextElementSibling;`

Getting the value of `element[i].nextElementSibling` change the variable `path` value,
but when I reassign the value of `element[i]`

`element[i] = path;`

the `element[i]` stay as it is. Why is this happening?

```js
/*
Press Ctrl+Shift+C while opening the web console with google chrome or mozzila firefox (Tools > Web Developer > Web Console) and hover over the element display by the console to highlight the element.
*/
let element = document.querySelectorAll("a");
console.log(element.length);
for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
 let path = element[i].nextElementSibling;
 //Is NOT next sibling element exist and is <p>
 if(!(path && path.matches("p"))){
  //path is null, reasign to <a>
  path = element[i];
  console.log("path = element[i] (Origin):");
  console.log(path = element[i]);
  //get <a> parent element
  path = path.parentElement;
  console.log("path = path.parentElement (Origin's Parent):");
  console.log(path); //display <div>
  if(path && path.nextElementSibling.matches("p")){
   //get destination
   element[i] = path.nextElementSibling;
   //fail to changed T_T
   console.log("element[i] = path.nextElementSibling; (Origin's Parent's Next Sibling)");
   console.log("'path.nextElementSibling' value:");
   console.log(path.nextElementSibling); //display <p>
   console.log("Value of 'element[i]' (did not change!):");
   console.log(element[i]); //why still <a>? not <p>
  }
 }else{ //sibling element
  element[i] = path;
  console.log("element[i] = path");
  console.log("'path' value:");
  console.log(path);
  console.log("Value of 'element[i]' (did not change!):");
  console.log(element[i]);
 }
 console.log("FINAL value of element[i]:");
 element[i].classList.add("get--target");
 console.log(element[i]);
}
```

```css
body{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 background: black;
}
div{
 background: navy;
 padding: 20px;
}
span{
 display: none;
 margin: 10px 0;
 padding: 10px;
}
a, .get--target{
 display: block;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 background: orange;
}
p{
 background: blue;
 padding: 10px;
}
p.get--target span{
 display: block;
 background: lightgreen;
}
a.get--target span{
 display: block;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div>
  <a href="#">Origin <span>Failed</span></a>
  <p>Destination <span>Success</span></p>
 </div>
 <p>Destination <span>Success</span></p>
</body>
```

P.S.
Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox have different display of console log
the the first result of `element[i]` that still not yet set to have `get--target` class, have in Google Chrome?
[Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox console log results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIoWW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is document.querySelectorAll() method will NodeList Object. The NodeList Object cannot be modified. Inorder to alter NodeList object you have to convert it into normal javascript array. Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[selector]')) will return javascript array instead of NodeList Object.Hope this helps.

```js
/*
Press Ctrl+Shift+C while opening the web console with google chrome or mozzila firefox (Tools > Web Developer > Web Console) and hover over the element display by the console to highlight the element.
*/
let element = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a"));
console.log(element.length);
for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
 let path = element[i].nextElementSibling;
 //Is NOT next sibling element exist and is <p>
 if(!(path && path.matches("p"))){
  //path is null, reasign to <a>
  path = element[i];
  console.log("path = element[i] (Origin):");
  console.log(path = element[i]);
  //get <a> parent element
  path = path.parentElement;
  console.log("path = path.parentElement (Origin's Parent):");
  console.log(path); //display <div>
  if(path && path.nextElementSibling.matches("p")){
   //get destination
   element[i] = path.nextElementSibling;
   //fail to changed T_T
   console.log("element[i] = path.nextElementSibling; (Origin's Parent's Next Sibling)");
   console.log("'path.nextElementSibling' value:");
   console.log(path.nextElementSibling); //display <p>
   console.log("Value of 'element[i]' (did not change!):");
   console.log(element[i]); //why still <a>? not <p>
  }
 }else{ //sibling element
  element[i] = path;
  console.log("element[i] = path");
  console.log("'path' value:");
  console.log(path);
  console.log("Value of 'element[i]' (did not change!):");
  console.log(element[i]);
 }
 console.log("FINAL value of element[i]:");
 element[i].classList.add("get--target");
 console.log(element[i]);
}
```

```css
body{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 background: black;
}
div{
 background: navy;
 padding: 20px;
}
span{
 display: none;
 margin: 10px 0;
 padding: 10px;
}
a, .get--target{
 display: block;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 background: orange;
}
p{
 background: blue;
 padding: 10px;
}
p.get--target span{
 display: block;
 background: lightgreen;
}
a.get--target span{
 display: block;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div>
  <a href="#">Origin <span>Failed</span></a>
  <p>Destination <span>Success</span></p>
 </div>
 <p>Destination <span>Success</span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. So NodeList is ready-only and can't manipulate elements? How about HTMLCollections? I heard about that. Anyway, that Array.from() method is news to me. Array.from() have many use, when is the right time to use that method? It will take time to me to understand that. I'll gonna read this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-method/. Thanks, I learn new today.